# Android Studio's Module settings don't affect gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For instance *Project Structure > MyModule > Dependencies* lets me change the scope setting of each dependency (Implementation, Api, provided, ...). However, those changes never result in the gradle file.

In fact, when I re-open *Project Structure > MyModule > Dependencies* after clicking "OK", the settings are unchanged.

[image: _Project Structure > MyModule > Dependencies_]

That behavior confused me a lot as I thought the settings of this dialog are stored somewhere else aside the gradle file.

Is that intented behavior? Do you also have that behavior in your projects?

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
```